# How can I check if the value in current row also present in one of the rows above and can get the corresponding value in the current row

Tags: excel, vba

This is part of the bigger process. The data is as below:

```
code        cat     Status
aa           A        K
aa           B        L
aa           C        M
aa           A  
aa           D
```

When the code reaches the 5th row, I want to check all the rows above and find out that for A category status is already assigned as K and put it in the current row as well then move to next row. It should check this for all the rows.

If the same category is not present in the above rows it should go to a different sheet named 'List' which has the code, cat level status info and pick that status.

Comment: share the next screen after the processing please, that will make a bit more understandable...

Comment: What should occur if category A with a valid status is *not* found above the current position?

Comment: There is whole lot of code where it goes to another sheet to get the status

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data is going to show an error when it gets to *Code: aa, Status: D* as there is no valid status above that point for the *aa, D* combination.

With that said, this should be your quickest method.

```
Dim rng As Range
With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = .Columns("C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX(R1C:R[-1]C, MIN(INDEX(ROW(R1:R[-1])+((R1C[-1]:R[-1]C[-1]<>RC[-1])+(R1C[-2]:R[-1]C[-2]<>RC[-2]))*1E+99, , ))), """")"
        rng = rng.Value
    End If
End With
```

If the sample data was not just a redacted typo, edit your question to include more specifics on special circumstances and more help can be forthcoming.